# fill an array with objects from other arrays

Tags: javascript

I have three arrays:

```
var arrayOne=[{obj1}, {obj2}, {ob3}];
var arrayTwo=[{obj4}, {obj5}, {obj6}];
var arrayThree=[{obj7}, {obj8}, {obj9}];
```

And I need to Know how to fill a new array with values from those arrays, like this:

```
var arrayFINAL=[{obj1}, {obj2}, {ob3}, {obj7}, {obj8}, {obj9}, {obj4}, {obj5}, {obj6}];
```

I thought it was something like this:

```
var arrayFINAL = new Array(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

But it seems to create an array an array's of arrays not an objects array.
Anyone knows how to do this? thnks!

Comment: ... why are you switching arrayTwo and arrayThree in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var combinedArray = arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> **Syntax**
>   array.concat(value1, value2, ..., valueN)

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/yUDgM/)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Array concatenation

```
arrayFinal = arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) for documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayFinal = arrayOne.concat(arrayThree,arrayTwo);
```

Comment: All of the answers are the same!

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

```
var arrayFINAL = new Array(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

Will make an array `arrayFINAL` with three members, each of which is another array, like a multidimensional array.

If you want to create a new array with all three, use the `concat()` operator...

```
var arrayFinal = arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkEuu/).

If you want to push them all onto the original array, use...

```
arrayOne.push.apply(arrayOne, arrayTwo.concat(arrayThree));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHhzq/).

Answer (score -1):

You may be interested in [`array_merge` from PHJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_merge:326) - the behaviour you're looking for is identical to what PHP's `array_merge` does, and the PHPJS version does the same in JavaScript.